# Displaying the full state or County name in Profile Listing

Tags: addresses, directory

I'm sure there is a simple solution to this that I'm missing - I have a custom profile that I'm setting up as a searchable directory that has a number of address fields displayed in the results
Country, State, city. - Home
Country, State, city. - Work
Country, State, city. - Other

The State field is returning as an abbreviation, or in the case of somewhere like France - a number. 
Is there a way to display- (or retrieve given the returned value ) the full state name?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the solution was one I'd be staring at for a while.

Administer > Localisation > Address Settings

change the Address Display for state/ province from {contact.state_province} to {contact.state_province_name}